# Using `types.DynamicFeeTx` for `EIP-1559` in golang creates an invalid raw transaction hex

Tags: go-ethereum, raw-transaction, encoding, eip-1559

I am trying to create a raw `EIP-1559` transaction using the `DynamicFeeTx` method since I want to provide a gas tip cap. When I create this raw transaction, sign it and encode it using rlp, I get a raw transaction that is invalid when I use https://www.ethereumdecoder.com/ to validate it. Here is my golang code:

```
    tx := types.NewTx(&types.DynamicFeeTx{
        Nonce:     nonce,
        GasFeeCap: gasFeeCap,
        GasTipCap: gasTipCap,
        Gas:       uint64(gasUsed),
        To:        &toAddress,
        Value:     new(big.Int),
        Data:      []byte(calldata),
        ChainID:   chainID,
    })

    signedTx, err := types.SignTx(tx, types.LatestSignerForChainID(chainID), model.TRANSACTION_PRIVATE_KEY_ECDSA)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    rawTxBytes, err := rlp.EncodeToBytes(signedTx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    rawTxHex := hex.EncodeToString(rawTxBytes)

    return fmt.Sprintf("0x%s", rawTxHex)
```

What is suprising is that if I use the old method and create the tx like so:

```
tx := types.NewTransaction(nonce, toAddress, new(big.Int), uint64(gasUsed), gasFeeCap, []byte(calldata))
```

Then it creates a raw transaction, which after encoding and hexifying, is valid using the `ethereumdecoder` link from above.

Am I missing a step? Is there a good guide I can follow that shows how to create and encode `DynamicFeeTx` transactions?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the issue. For a DynamicFeeTx `rlp` should not be used, should use `signedTx.MarshalBinary()`